# Installing a epson stylus SX200

Tags: drivers

I have a Epson Stylus SX200 Printer/Scanner. I have managed to install the printer but cannot install the scanner - HELP

Answer (score 0):

Epson has their own handy driver for the scanners, which can be downloaded from http://support.epson.net/linux/en/iscan_c.php?version=1.0.4, and instructions for the package are at http://download.ebz.epson.net/man/linux/iscan_e.html#sec6-1

The basics of the installation are to download the appropriate .deb file (probably the 64 bit version) and then...

Open a terminal window (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>)

```
cd Downloads 
tar xvfz iscan-bundle-1.0.4.x64.deb.tar.gz
cd iscan-bundle-1.0.4.x64.deb
./install.sh
```